# GitHub Actions: share common actions between jobs

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-actions

Switching from [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions), I was wondering if there is a way to share common steps between jobs. For a project, I need each job to start with 3 actions: check out repository code, install Node.js v12, restore node_modules from the cache (if available). Actually I have added these 3 actions for each job, which works but is a bit verbose. Is there a way to say: "Each job must run these actions first" or something like that?

```yaml
name: ci
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Cache node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

  test_mysql:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Restore node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Test MySQL 5
        run: npm run test-mysql
        env:
          DOCKER_MYSQL_TAG: 5

      - name: Test MySQL 8
        run: npm run test-mysql
        env:
          DOCKER_MYSQL_TAG: 8

  test_postgres:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Restore node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Test Postgres 10
        run: npm run test-postgres
        env:
          DOCKER_POSTGRES_TAG: 10

      - name: Test Postgres 11
        run: npm run test-postgres
        env:
          DOCKER_POSTGRES_TAG: 11

      - name: Test Postgres 12
        run: npm run test-postgres
        env:
          DOCKER_POSTGRES_TAG: 12

  test_mariadb:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Restore node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Test MariaDB 10.4
        run: npm run test-mariadb
        env:
          DOCKER_MARIADB_TAG: 10.4.12

  test_mssql:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Restore node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Test MSSQL 2017
        run: npm run test-mssql
        env:
          DOCKER_MSSQL_TAG: 2017-CU17-ubuntu

      - name: Test MSSQL 2019
        run: npm run test-mssql
        env:
          DOCKER_MSSQL_TAG: 2019-latest

  test_sqlite:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Restore node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Test SQLite
        run: npm run test-sqlite

  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [test_mysql, test_postgres, test_mariadb, test_mssql, test_sqlite]
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12'

      - name: Restore node_modules
        id: cache-node-modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Check version changes
        uses: EndBug/version-check@v1
        id: check

      - name: Publish
        if: steps.check.outputs.changed == 'true' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
        run: |
          npm set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
          npm set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken ${{ secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN }}
          npm publish
```

Answer (score 2):

Now is possible to use uses in composite actions - please check [this link](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/)

Composite action:

```yaml
name: "Publish to Docker"
description: "Pushes built artifacts to Docker"

inputs:
  registry_username:
    description: “Username for image registry”
    required: true
  registry_password:
    description: “Password for image registry”
    required: true

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{inputs.registry_username}}
          password: ${{inputs.registry_password}}

      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
```

And then:

```yaml
on: [push]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: my-org/publish-docker@v1
        with:
          registry_username: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME}}
          registry_password: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD}}
```

**Original reply:**

It looks that at the moment is not possible if among steps you want to share are `uses`.

It should be handled by [composite actions but](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646)

> **What does composite run steps currently support?**
>
> For each run step in a composite action, we support:
>
> - name
> - id
> - run
> - env
> - shell
> - working-directory
>
> In addition, we support mapping input and outputs throughout the action.
>
> See docs for more info.
>
> **What does Composite Run Steps Not Support**
>
> We don't support setting conditionals, continue-on-error, timeout-minutes, **"uses"**, and secrets on individual steps within a composite action right now.

Comment: Interesting, maybe they will support uses as well in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I hope, they will add that soon! I know that this is not kind of answer you would like to get but since there is technical limitation please consider accepting this answer if no one gives you a better idea.

Comment: composite actions accept `uses:` now https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/